# SoapClient: Detecting optional/required arguments?

Tags: php, xsd, soap-client

What is the simplest (or any) way to figure out if a specific argument for a soap call is optional/required? I'm currently using SoapClient (in WSDL mode) to create SoapUI-like functionality. The only thing I still need at this point is figure out optional and required parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the WSDL file for your web service, you can see the request schema. The optional/required depends on minOccurs and maxOccurs attributes on the elements of this xsd. By default minOccurs and maxOccurs on `<xsd:element>`, `<xsd:sequence>`, `<xsd:all>`, `<xsd:choice>`... are 1, so by default all elements are required. If there are some elements which has minOccurs="0" as attribute, then this elements will be optional.

i.e you have this xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="shiporder">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="shipto">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="country" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="item">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
            <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
            <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

In the xsd above the `<city>` and `<country>` elements in `<shipto>` sequence are optional. The `<item>` sequence are also optional, and if `<item>` appears the `<note>` within this sequence is also optional. The rest are required.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Yeah that's how I ended up doing it. Naturally not a single WSDL that doesn't use dependant XMLs to define the types, so I ended up "borrowing" code from [https://github.com/staabm/soap-client-generator/blob/master/WSDLInterpreter.php#L164] to include all imports/includes/wsdl's. Your answers is perfectly clear and would've solved the problem for me if I was still stuck, so thank you for the effort :)

Comment: So I'm late... anyway thank you for the acceptance :).

Comment: Late for me, but hopefully very timely for everyone else with the same question :)